# Display images dynamically using map() in react not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to display images in the sports array using map(). but not working

```
<div className="row">
   {this.state.sports.map(function(sport, index){
     return (
     <div className="col-md-3" key={index}>
       <h3 className="text-center">{this.state.sports.name}</h3>
       <img src={ require('./../assets/images/'+ {this.state.sports.name} +'.jpg') } width="300px" height="180px" />
       <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit" onClick={this.join_in_sport} >JOIN</button>
     </div>
    )
  }.bind(this))}
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working really? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: you are iterating `this.state.sports` so it is an Array.
later you do `this.state.sports.name` this will be undefined in `img` DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in how you are building the pathname for your image. Same for your `<h3>` tag.

```
src={ require('./../assets/images/'+ {this.state.sports.name} +'.jpg') }
```

If `this.state.sports` is an array, and not an object, then it can't possibly have a `name` key. I think you meant to print the current objects `name` for each iteration in your `map()`.

So try:

```
<h3 className="text-center">{this.state.sports.name}</h3>
<img src={ require('./../assets/images/'+ {sport.name} +'.jpg') } width="300px" height="180px" />
```

This is assuming your array looks something like:

```
[
  {name: "foo"},
  {name: "bar"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem,
the image folder in src doesn't work.
I moved the image folder to public and it works fine.

```
function App() {
  

 
  const moviesData = [
  
      name: "Terminator: Dark Fate",
      img: "./badboy3.jpg", //image in public folder
    },
  ];

  const movieList = moviesData.map((movie, i) => {
    return <Movie key={i} movieName={movie.name} movieImg={movie.img} />;
  });

  return (
    <div>
  
     {movieList}
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following the React beginners tutorial tried to call images dynamically by importing them as variables but this simply didn't work when trying to call them in another file (App.js) using the .map() function. Code below:

import katieImg from "../images/Katie.png";
import starImg from "../images/Katie.png";

```
export default [
  {
    img: { katieImg },
    star: { starImg },
    rating: "5.0",
    reviewCount: 6,
    location: "USA",
    title: "Life Lessons with Katie Zaferes",
    price: 136,
  },
];
```

So instead I had to get rid of the dynamically imported variables and put the images folder in the public folder. This worked. Code below:

```
export default [
  {
    img: "../images/Katie.png",
    star: "../images/Star.png",
    rating: "5.0",
    reviewCount: 6,
    location: "USA",
    title: "Life Lessons with Katie Zaferes",
    price: 136,
  },
];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).